# Word every 2 bits to symbol

Tags: c

I have a function that read a word, bit by bit and change to symbol:

I need help to change it to read every 2 bits and change to symbol.
I don't have an idea for it and I need your help guys

```
void PrintWeirdBits(word w , char* buf){
    word mask = 1<<(BITS_IN_WORD-1);
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<BITS_IN_WORD;i++){
        if(mask & w)
            buf[i]='/';
        else
            buf[i]='.';
        mask>>=1;
    }
    buf[i] = '\0';
}
```

Needed symbols:

```
00 - *
01 - #
10 - %
11 - !
```

Comment: When you say, "read 2 bits and convert to symbol" which symbols should it be converted to?  Hint - you should use a mask with 2 bits as 1 and right shift by 2 every time.

Comment: @RishikeshRaje Edited. yea I know, but cant understand how to change it to 2 bits. can you show an example please?

Comment: How is the datatype `word` defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my proposal for your issue.
Using a lookup table for the symbol decoding will eliminate the need in `if` statements.

(I assumed `word` is an unsigned 16 bits data type)

```
#define BITS_PER_SIGN 2
#define BITS_PER_SIGN_MSK 3 // decimal 3 is 0b11 in binary --> two bits set
                            // General define could be:
                            //        ((1u << BITS_PER_SIGN) - 1)
#define INIT_MASK (BITS_PER_SIGN_MSK << (BITS_IN_WORD - BITS_PER_SIGN))

void PrintWeirdBits(word w , char* buf)
{
    static const char signs[] = {'*', '#', '%', '!'};
    unsigned mask = INIT_MASK;
    int i;
    int sign_idx;

    for(i=0; i < BITS_IN_WORD / BITS_PER_SIGN; i++)
    {
        // the  bits of the sign represent the index in the signs array
        // just need to align these bits to start from bit 0
        sign_idx = (w & mask) >> (BITS_IN_WORD - (i + 1)*BITS_PER_SIGN);
        // store the decoded sign in the buffer
        buf[i] = signs[sign_idx];
        // update the mask for the next symbol
        mask >>= BITS_PER_SIGN;
    }

    buf[i] = '\0';
}
```

[Here](https://ideone.com/TCDwo4) it seems to be working.
With small effort it can be updated to a generic code for any bit width of the symbol as long as it is power of two (1, 2, 4, 8) and smaller that `BITS_IN_WORD`.

Comment: I guess it would be nice to define `BITS_PER_SIGN_MSK` as `0x3` to accent it is related to binary representation.

Comment: @asikorski Sure, I'll add this as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `word` is `unsigned int` or an unsigned integer type.

```
void PrintWeirdBits(word w , char* buf){
    word mask = 3 << (BITS_IN_WORD -2);
    int i;
    word cmp;
    for(i=0;i<BITS_IN_WORD/2;i++){
        cmp = (mask & w) >> (BITS_IN_WORD -2 -2i);
        if(cmp == 0x00)
        {
            buf[i]='*'; 
        }
        else if (cmp == 0x01)
        {
            buf[i]='#'; 
        }
        else if (cmp == 0x02)
        {
            buf[i]='%'; 
        }
        else
        {
            buf[i]='!';
        }
        mask>>=2;
    }
    buf[i] = '\0';
}
```

The important part is

```
cmp = (mask & w) >> (BITS_IN_WORD -2 -2i);
```

Here `mask` and the input `w` is bitwise ANDed and the result is right shifted to get the value in the first two bits. These bits are compared to get the result.